# Why WPF turns my blue and red image into a blurred into purple

Tags: css, wpf, image, xaml

I noticed that if I include an Image element in my WPF application, the image comes out blurry on the screen. To test this, I reduced my program to the bare minimum and created a test image. I tried this in an out-of-browser Silverlight application and in a regular WPF application. I targeted .NET 4 and 4.5. See the same result in all cases.

### Test Image

3 pixels wide by 3 pixels high. The middle pixel is red. All others pixels are blue. You can also see it at http://imageshack.com/a/img538/5335/GM4B8I.png

### XAML

The entire XAML page is shown below. I added an empty Label above the image and to the left of the image to move it away from the edge of the window.

```
<Page x:Class="Demo.Home"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
  mc:Ignorable="d" 
  d:DesignHeight="486" d:DesignWidth="864"
Title="Demo">

<StackPanel Background="white" Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label FontSize="10" Content=" "/>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label FontSize="10" Content=" "/>
        <Image Source="/Demo;component/test.png
               HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"
               Stretch="None" />
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

### RESULT:

The 3x3 image is blurred into a 4x4 image. Instead of original blue and red pixels, the pixels are different shades of purple. http://imageshack.com/a/img661/3707/TFdtnF.png

What is causing the blurring? How can I avoid it?

Comment: Does your test use WPF or Silverlight? ("Label" is a WPF thing, not Silverlight).

Comment: This is out-of-browser Silverlight. Not sure if browser-based Silverlight supports labels, but out-of-browser Silverlight does.

Comment: Just tested this in a new WPF project (as opposed to Silverlight) and see the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

`RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality"`

to the image.

Answer (score 0):

The blurring results from WPF using sub-pixel precision to calculate position for the Image. The three-pixel image ends up being rendered at non-integer pixel positions, so WPF spreads it over 4 device pixels.

Attempting to fix this using SnapsToDevicePixels did not work. WPF ignores SnapsToDevicePixels for images.

Here is a solution that works http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/10/05/blurry-bitmaps.aspx